# POINT and VALUE to Multipoint

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table of geom(POINT) and a value. How can I turn turning this into a Multipoint geometry so I can use it in interpolate?
The end goal is to use this just using my Points and values.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' as type, array_to_json(array_agg(feats)) as features 
      FROM 
         (SELECT 'Feature' as type, 
                 st_asgeojson((gv).geom)::json as geometry, 
                 row_to_json((SELECT props FROM (SELECT (gv).val as value) as props )) as properties  
            FROM 
(SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(
          ST_SetValue(
              ST_SetValue(
                  ST_InterpolateRaster(
                        'MULTIPOINT(10.5 9.5 1, 11.5 8.5 2, 10.5 8.5 3, 11.5 9.5 4)'::geometry,
                        'invdist:smoothing:2.0',
                        ST_AddBand(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(100, 100, 0.0005, 0.0005, 1, 1, 0, 0), '16BSI')
                        ), 
                    2, 2, 10), 
            1, 1, NULL)
     ) gv 
 )json
    ) feats 
) fc;
```

In order to create the Raster I have tried with but the problem is that I need a Z value in the `geom`.

```
CREATE TABLE wa_rast AS
WITH inputs AS (
  SELECT
    500::float8 AS pixelsize,
    'invdist:power:5.5:smoothing:2.0' AS algorithm,
    st_collect(geog::geometry) AS geom,
    ST_Expand(st_collect(geog::geometry), 100000) AS ext
  FROM sources
),
sizes AS (
  SELECT
    ceil((ST_XMax(ext) - ST_XMin(ext))/pixelsize)::integer AS width,
    ceil((ST_YMax(ext) - ST_YMin(ext))/pixelsize)::integer AS height,
    ST_XMin(ext) AS upperleftx,
    ST_YMax(ext) AS upperlefty
  FROM inputs
)
-- Feed it all into interpolation
SELECT 1 AS rid,
  ST_InterpolateRaster(
    geom,
    algorithm,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_AddBand(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(width, height, upperleftx, upperlefty, pixelsize), '16BSI'), ST_SRID(geom))
  ) AS rast
FROM sizes, inputs;
```

so this returns

```
ERROR:  RASTER_InterpolateRaster: input geometry does not have Z values
SQL state: XX000
```

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the interpolation function?

Comment: @BERA ST_InterpolateRaster so i need something like this 'MULTIPOINT(10.5 9.5 1000, 11.5 8.5 1000, 10.5 8.5 500, 11.5 9.5 500)'::geometry,

Comment: @BERA I updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: So I need to make the geom table into a multipoint geom table by combining it with the values from my understanding.

Comment: Will test it, but looks promising

Comment: I ran the whole thing and pgadmin crashed so don't know if that is a good or bad thing

Comment: @BERA Can ST_expand be used on ST_union or does it only work on St_Collect?

Comment: @BERA I did some tweaking to what you said and ended up with some what of a reulst. Could you take a look at my last problem? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431238/interpolated-for-every-point-in-the-raster-space